# Set height of child to height of parent

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

So, I am trying to create the following grid/table layout:

```css
.grid-column {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.grid-column .grid-column-content {} .wireframe {
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wireframe" style="display: inline-block;">
  <div class="grid-column red">
    <div class="grid-column-content" style="margin: 5px;">
      <span>Some content</span>
      <br/>
      <span>More content</span>
      <br/>
      <span>Some more content</span>
      <br/>
      <span>Even more content!!!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column green" style="min-width: 300px;">
    <div class="grid-column-content blue" style="margin: 5px;">
      Hi
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Essentially, it's two (or more) `div`s that are set to display as `table-cell`.
Inside the `div`(s) can be any kind of content.

[image: No Fill]

**Example:** The left `div` contains a larger amount of content and is responsible for the `height` of the container `div`. The right `div` has a smaller amount of content and **it does not fill the entire `height`**. Even if the `height` is set to `100%` for the right content, it still does not fill.

It **should** look like this:

[image: Fill with absolute positioning]

I achieved the look above by using `absolute` positioning, but using `absolute` positioning, the content is taken out of the layout system and it doesn't resize the parent if it becomes the larger content.

[image: Fill with absolute positioning more content]

So I can't:

- Use absolute positioning
- Set the height of the 'table' div (top level div in the example)
- Set any kind of fixed heights anywhere!
- Use CSS3 Flexbox (must be compatible with early browsers)

**Why is this so hard to do in CSS? This is like Layout 101.**

Does anyone know of a solution? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your requirements, you can do this using **CSS tables** nesting them.

**OP Comment**

> One of my requirements of what NOT to do was to set the `height` of the
>   top level `div` (wireframe). You created a class called '`table`' and set
>   the `height` to `100%`. This poses a problem because if the `body` and `html`
>   element are also set to `100%` `height` then the `table` fills the entire
>   viewport's `height`

You can do some workaround by using `max-height` in `.table` which will override  `height: 100%`, However you need to set the `max-height`  from the cell who will have less content.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%
}
.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  /* optional */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100px
}
.wireframe {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
}
.grid-column {
  display: table-cell
}
.red {
  background-color: red
}
.green {
  background-color: green
}
.green .table {
  border-spacing: 5px
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wireframe table">
  <div class="grid-column red">
    <span>Some content</span>
    <br/>
    <span>More content</span>
    <br/>
    <span>Some more content</span>
    <br/>
    <span>Even more content!!!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column green">
    <div class="grid-column-content table">
      <div class="grid-column blue">
        HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi HiHi 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**OP comment**

> It seems that using Flexbox is the only way to do what I want while keeping the height dynamic.

So here is a `flexbox` solution:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.wireframe {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
}
.grid-column {
  flex: 1
}
.red {
  background-color: red
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
  display:flex;
  padding: 5px
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wireframe flex">
  <div class="grid-column red">
    <span>Some content</span>
    <br/>
    <span>More content</span>
    <br/>
    <span>Some more content</span>
    <br/>
    <span>Even more content!!!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column green">
      <div class="grid-column blue">
        Hi
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You got me. Somehow for 10 mins I couldn't do that in code snippet. Weird tho.

Comment: Ha!   +1  from me, but a few other guys just voted me down completely for a similar answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/37932179/5641669

Comment: One of my requirements of what NOT to do was to set the height of the top level div (wireframe). You created a class called 'table' and set the height to 100%. This poses a problem because if the body and html element are also set to 100% height then the table fills the entire viewport's height.

https://jsfiddle.net/tmk8zkeb/

Comment: @Johannes I saw your answer, I find it weird too..go figure, maybe next time answer with table and advise not to use it in a note, usually I do that

Comment: @BradleyOdell why should you have the `body,html {height:100%}`  ? unless if you want something to fill the viewport's height, are you going to have something to fill the viewport height? if not that the rule doesn't make sense and my code will apply well

Comment: otherwise you are asking for the impossible

Comment: I have an existing layout of 3 columns which fill the entire viewport. If I don't have the html and body set to 100% height then the layout doesn't stretch to the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: care to share the link? you always can set a `max-height` on `.table` which will override the `height:100%`

Comment: I don't have a public link. It's an internal site and I can't share any source. I tried to abstract that part away by just requiring the top level table div to not have the height set. I might just have to use Flexbox and reduce the compatibility of my site because it seems like basic HTML and CSS can't accomplish this.

Comment: want me to update the answer with 2 options? this one with max-height and flexbox?

Comment: If you want you can update the answer with flexbox. It seems that using Flexbox is the only way to do what I want while keeping the height dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

The only working way which is required to work by the CSS 2.1 spec is taking the inner element out-of-flow:

```css
.grid-column {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.grid-column:nth-child(2) > .grid-column-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```css
.grid-column {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.grid-column:nth-child(2) > .grid-column-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.wireframe {
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wireframe" style="display: inline-block;" >
  <div class="grid-column red">
    <div class="grid-column-content" style="margin: 5px;">
      <div>Some content</div>
      <div>More content</div>
      <div>Some more content</div>
      <div>Even more content!!!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column green" style="min-width: 300px;">
    <div class="grid-column-content blue" style="margin: 5px;">
      Hi
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, the behavior is implementation-dependent. The cell is required to be at least as tall as the content, so if you could make the content to be as tall as the cell, it would be a circular definition.

If you use absolute positioning, the content no longer has an impact on the height of the cell, so the circle is broken and the behavior is well-defined.

Alternatively, I would recommend flexbox, a new layout designed to handle situations like this.

Comment: Yeah it might be a circular definition. But setting the content the height of the cell does not violate the original requirement since the cell would still be at least as tall as the content.

Comment: @BradleyOdell The problem is that there infinitely many possible heights that would fulfill the percentages, which one should the browser choose? If you could use `height: 100%` without problems, why not `height: 200%`? But that must break in some way. The spec does not define these cases, so implementations can do what they want. Don't take it for granted it will work everywhere everytime, even if it behaves like you want on your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found your HTML pretty confused:

1) try to write the style where it belongs... to the css file, not in the HTML tags!

2) the html structure is all messed up... try to keep vertical elements grouped in a "wrapper" box that defines the horizontal space.

You can try my solution here: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/c8OH4sonV9MnhhRLdDOT?p=preview

**HTML:**

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="left-column red">
      <div class="content">
        <span>Some content</span>
        <br/>
        <span>More content</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Some more content</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Even more content!!!</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right-column green">
      <div class="content">
        Hi
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.left-column {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.right-column {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.right-column .content {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

I used the flex-box css feature to define the wrapper around the two columns, in this way it's easier to read and to mantain.
Hope it helps, but keep studying! :)